# Need direction on writing custom datetime formatting in VB6

Tags: vb6, datetimepicker

I have a string:

```
A -DDD HH:MM:SS
```

and currently trying to write a function that will take in this string and also the format to convert it to.  For example, say I wanted to display just the HH:MM ss (Hours with leading Zeros + colon + Minutes with leading Zeros + no colons + seconds without leading Zeros.

I understand for VB6 you'd probably use a string function like Mid(str, int, int) to get the time portion.  But if I create a custom format of

```
HH:MM ss
```

How would you approach formating this?

J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chop off the strictly formatted time part and use the format function;

```
s = "A -??? 12:34:56"
t = right$(s,8)

?format$(t, "HH:NN ss")
12:34 56

?format$(t, "HH:NN ss AM/PM")
12:34 56 PM

?format$(t, "H, N, S  AM/PM")
12, 34, 56  PM
```

(N is minute here)

Comment: Thanks Alex K, that did exactly what I needed it to.

Comment: You welcome, I just noticed you can infact use MM in these cases

Comment: @AlexK. I always forget, what is the purpose of using the dollar sign again?

Comment: The $ on the end of a function that returns a string means it returns a string directly, as opposed to returning a string by the way of a variant